# Brightcove video gallery

Tags: brightcove

I'm building a video database and using Brightcove as my video provider. I my database returns a list of video IDs and on select, that video should load into a div and begin to play.

So far I have this:

http://bigreviewtv.byteserve.com.au/bcgal2.html

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

 <script src="/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences_all.js"></script>
 <script>
 newVideo = function(videoId) {
         var newhtml = [
       '<object id="myExperience', videoId, '" class="BrightcoveExperience">'
       , '<param name="bgcolor"          value="#FFFFFF" />'
       , '<param name="width"            value="480" />'
       , '<param name="height"           value="270" />'
       , '<param name="playerKey"        value="AQ~~,AAACP3r8R8k~,kFpRRbL5Evyu4ko-Z7yiuqqeHKzo4hSs" />'
       , '<param name="playerID"         value="2472217790001" />'
       , '<param name="isVid"            value="true" />'
       , '<param name="isUI"             value="true" />'    
       , '<param name="@videoPlayer"     value="' + videoId + '" />'
       , '<param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />'    
     , '</object>'
     ];
     //return $(newhtml.join('')).appendTo('#hero');
     //$("#hero").html(newhtml.join(''));
     //alert(newhtml.join(''));

     brightcove.createExperiences();
   };



 </script>

 </HEAD>
 <BODY>

 <div id="hero" style="border:1px red dotted">

 <object id="myExperience2472866007001" class="BrightcoveExperience">
   <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
   <param name="width" value="480" />
   <param name="height" value="270" />
   <param name="playerID" value="2472217790001" />
   <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAACP3r8R8k~,kFpRRbL5Evyu4ko-Z7yiuqqeHKzo4hSs" />
   <param name="isVid" value="true" />
   <param name="isUI" value="true" />
   <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
   <param name="@videoPlayer" value="2472866007001" />
 </object>

 </div>



<div id="video-gallery">
  <div id="video-full"></div>
  <ul id="video-thumbs">
 <li><a href="javascript:newVideo('2472862365001')">Video 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:newVideo(2472940937001)">Video 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:newVideo(2472916922001)">Video 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /#video-gallery -->


</BODY>
</HTML>


<script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script>
```

Unfortunately it's not working as expected. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would be best to use the loadVideoByID() method in the Brightcove API - http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/reference/symbols/brightcove.api.modules.VideoPlayerModule.html#loadVideoByID

Here is an example:

```
<object id="myExperience921449663001" class="BrightcoveExperience">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
    <param name="width" value="480" />
    <param name="height" value="270" />
    <param name="playerID" value="2079935931001" />
    <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAAA1oy1bvE~,ALl2ezBj3WE0z3yX6Xw29sdCvkH5GCJv" />
    <param name="isVid" value="true" />
    <param name="isUI" value="true" />
    <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
    <param name="@videoPlayer" value="921449663001" />

    <param name="includeAPI" value="true" />
    <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="onTemplateLoad" />
    <param name="templateReadyHandler" value="onTemplateReady" />
</object>
<script type="text/javascript">
brightcove.createExperiences();

function onTemplateLoad(experienceID) {
    player = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID);
    APIModules = brightcove.api.modules.APIModules;
}

function onTemplateReady(evt) {
    videoPlayer = player.getModule(APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
}
</script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:videoPlayer.loadVideoByID(928199562001)">928199562001</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:videoPlayer.loadVideoByID(1325817301001)">1325817301001</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:videoPlayer.loadVideoByID(1187545001001)">1187545001001</a></li>
</ul>
```

You would need to change the playerID, playerKey, @videoPlayer and videoIDs to suit your environment.

There are articles and sample code that walk through how to do this at http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/samples/fetch-playlists.html and http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/dynamically-loading-videos-using-smart-player-api

Comment: Sorry, reading on an iPhone and missed the example above. Thanks. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ahh, scratch that. I was trying to access it before the JS library was completely loaded. Time to do some tutorials.